# A box contains m white balls and n black balls

Tags: probability

This is an example from Probability, Random Variables and Stochastic Process by Papoulis

A box contains m white balls and n black balls. Balls are drawn at random one at a time without replacement. Find the probability of encountering a white ball by the kth draw.

$W_k=$ {a white ball is drawn by the kth draw}

$X_i=$ {i black balls followed by a white ball are drawn}

$W_k=X_0\cup X_1\cup... \cup X_{k-1}$

The probability for the first white ball to be drawn is:

$P(X_0)=\dfrac{m}{m+n}$

$P(X_1)=\dfrac{n}{m+n}.\dfrac{m}{m+n-1}$

This is what offered in the book, I try to write down a few more examples to get a grip of it:

$P(X_2)=\dfrac{n}{m+n}.\dfrac{n-1}{m+n-1}.\dfrac{m}{m+n-2}$

$P(X_3)=\dfrac{n}{m+n}.\dfrac{n-1}{m+n-1}.\dfrac{n-2}{m+n-2}.\dfrac{m}{m+n-3}$

The book writes:

$P(X_{k-1})=\dfrac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)m}{(m+n)(m+n-1)...(m+n-k+1)}.$

I don't understand this part, which is a general form of the above result.

Then the author writes that:
$P(W_k)=\dfrac{m}{m+n}(1+\dfrac{n}{m+n-1}+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{(m+n-1)(m+n-2)}+...\dfrac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{(m+n-1)(m+n-2)...(m+n-k+1)}$

I don't understand this part as well.

By the $(n+1)$st draw, we must have a white ball, hence $P(W_{n+1})=1$
Why is it equal 1, I don't get this part.

The last part of this example is also beyond my understanding:

$1+\dfrac{n}{m+n-1}+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{(m+n-1)(m+n-2)}+...+\dfrac{n(n-1)...2.1}{(m+n-1)(m+n-2)...(m+1)m}=\dfrac{m+n}{m}$

I don't understand this equality, how can the left side is equal to right side?

Comment: A partial suggestion: Maybe the very last equation in your question can be proven to be true by induction?

Comment: It may help you to see $n-k+1$ as $n-(k-1)$

Comment: Did you mean to write $\Pr(X_{k - 1})$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Yes that's what I mean. I have corrected the typo.

Comment: Please help! Anyone?

Comment: Ignoring that wall of text, I think it is easiest to approach the problem by noting that the opposite event to $W_k$ is that within $k$ draws they are all black.  You have then $Pr(W_k)=1-Pr(W_k^c) = 1 - \dfrac{\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{n+m}{k}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations for $\Pr(X_2)$ and $\Pr(X_3)$ are correct.

By definition, $\Pr(X_{k - 1})$ is the probability that $k - 1$ black balls are drawn before a white ball is drawn on the $k$th draw, which is
\begin{align*}
\Pr(X_{k - 1}) & = \frac{n}{m + n} \cdot \frac{n - 1}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 2}{m + n - 2} \ldots \frac{n - (k - 2)}{m + n - (k - 2)} \cdot \frac{m}{m + n - (k - 1)}\\
               & = \frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2) \ldots (n - k + 2)m}{(m + n)(m + n - 1)(m + n - 2) \ldots (m + n - k + 2)(m + n - k + 1)}
\end{align*}
since there are $n - (j - 1)$ black balls left from which to choose on the $j$th draw, where $1 \leq j \leq k - 1$, out of $m + n - (j - 1)$ balls in total, and there are $m$ white balls from which to draw out of $m + n - (k - 1)$ balls in total on the $k$th draw.

Therefore, the book appears to have an indexing error.

Since $\Pr(W_k)$ represents the probability that a white ball is drawn by the $k$th draw, 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(W_k) & = \Pr(X_0) + \Pr(X_1) + \Pr(X_2) + \cdots + \Pr(X_{k - 1})\\
         & = \frac{m}{m + n} + \frac{n}{m + n} \cdot \frac{m}{m + n - 1} + \frac{n}{m + n} \cdot \frac{n - 1}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{m}{m + n - 2}\\
         & \qquad + \frac{n}{m + n} \cdot \frac{n - 1}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 2}{m + n - 2} \ldots \frac{n - (k - 2)}{m + n - (k - 2)} \cdot \frac{m}{m + n - (k - 1)}\\
        & = \frac{m}{m + n}\left[1 + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 1}{m + n - 2} + \ldots \right.\\
        & \qquad \left. + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 2}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 3}{m + n - 2} \ldots \frac{n - (k - 2)}{m + n - (k - 1)}\right]
\end{align*}
where we have factored out an $m$ from the last term in the numerator and an $m + n$ from the first term in the denominator.

Since there are only $n$ black balls, we are guaranteed to obtain a white ball by the $(n + 1)$st draw.  Since $W_{n + 1}$ is the event that we draw a white ball by the $(n + 1)$st draw, $\Pr(W_{n + 1}) = 1$.

Notice that 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(W_{n + 1}) & = \Pr(X_0) + \Pr(X_1) + \Pr(X_2) + \cdots + \Pr(X_{k - 1}) + \Pr(X_n)\\
         & = \frac{m}{m + n} + \frac{n}{m + n} \cdot \frac{m}{m + n - 1} + \frac{n}{m + n} \cdot \frac{n - 1}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{m}{m + n - 2}\\
         & \quad + \frac{n}{m + n} \cdot \frac{n - 1}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 2}{m + n - 2} \ldots \frac{n - (n - 2)}{m + n - (n - 2)} \cdot \frac{m}{m + n - (n - 1)}\\
        & \qquad + \frac{n}{m + n} \cdot \frac{n - 1}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 2}{m + n - 2} \ldots \frac{n - (n - 2)}{m + n - (n - 2)} \cdot \frac{n - (n - 1)}{m + n - (n - 1)} \cdot \frac{m}{m + n - n}\\
        & = \frac{m}{m + n}\left[1 + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 1}{m + n - 2} + \ldots \right.\\
        & \qquad \left. + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 2}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 3}{m + n - 2} \ldots \frac{n - (n - 2)}{m + n - (n - 1)}\right.\\
        & \qquad \left. + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 2}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 3}{m + n - 2} \ldots \frac{2}{m + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{m}\right]
\end{align*}
Substituting $1$ for $W_{n + 1}$ yields
\begin{align*}
1 & = \frac{m}{m + n}\left[1 + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 1}{m + n - 2} + \ldots \right.\\
        & \qquad \left. + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 2}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 3}{m + n - 2} \ldots \frac{n - (n - 2)}{m + n - (n - 1)}\right.\\
        & \qquad \left. + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 2}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 3}{m + n - 2} \ldots \frac{2}{m + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{m}\right]
\end{align*}
from which we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\frac{m + n}{m} & = \left[1 + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 1}{m + n - 2} + \ldots \right.\\
        & \qquad \left. + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 2}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 3}{m + n - 2} \ldots \frac{n - (n - 2)}{m + n - (n - 1)}\right.\\
        & \qquad \left. + \frac{n}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 2}{m + n - 1} \cdot \frac{n - 3}{m + n - 2} \ldots \frac{2}{m + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{m}\right]
\end{align*}
Having said all that, I agree with the comment posted by JMoravitz.  It is also how I approach such problems.